# How to unpack EaseUs Todo backup .PBD files on Ubuntu

Tags: backup, file-format

I have a .PBD backup file of my old Windows laptop.  This is created by the EaseUs Todo Backup utility.  They don't make it for Ubuntu.

Is there any way to unpack this file in an Ubuntu-native way?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

.PBD files are proprietary.

There are no known open source or Linux tools capable of opening them.

EaseUS carefully made it that way.

Comment: I ended up running EaseUS on a Windows machine.  It failed to recover many of the files.  I used the free version. In retrospect I would have been much better off with 7zip or gzip or tar.